# I want Theme developer to have admin access to WP but not civicrm, is that possible?

Tags: admin

I am using WP, and I have a theme developer helping me with a few issues in a buddypress forum, and then I have another plugin developer I would like to help me with another issue having to deal with super security. Anyway, I don't want so many people having access to my civicrm database as they don't need to touch civicrm in order to fix WP or plugin issues.

Is there a way to limit WP admin access to NOT allow access to civicrm?

Thanks?
If not, does anyone know a developer who knows WP, Civicrm, Thrive Theme, and BPS Security? I tried a Civi911 developer and they couldn't help me with all these WP plugin/theme/forum issues.

Comment: There's a plugin that does what you want  https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/, but I'm not sure if you can do it with the 'Free' version, the Pro version can limit access to admin pages un o Role/User basis inncluding Administrators

Comment: Thx so much Andrei! I'll check it out. I like paying for things that bring me value.

Comment: It's a good piece of software, and it's definitely worth it.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't hire an IT person who thinks it's ok to do  development on a live site. You always do development and testing on a COPY of the site. See also https://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress

One of many reasons is that the dev copy can have fake or anonymized data in it - I assume your concern is the devs seeing the real data.

Comment: Thank you, Demerit! That's good advice that I should consider taking myself as I am tinkering.